# Ritardando in the score

Tags: software, tempo

How do I write Ritardando (rit.) in a score, so that it will also affect the midi playback?
I can write rit. as a text marking, but it won't be heard it in the midi playback.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Also, consider that "rit." can sometimes mean "ritenuto", which is *not* the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Some software doesn't have a designated way to add a Ritardando (or similar gradual tempo change terms) to a score.  This could be because the *curve of change* isn't necessarily a simple straight line. Or because these terms aren't defined precisely; some uses of the same term could (and should) be interpreted quite differently.

One method to overcome this, is to add a sequence of (invisible) tempo changes (perhaps one per beat). You will have to figure out the individual tempi yourself.

However, some software will provide a method of appointing a curve of change, but it's hard to be specific without knowing the particular software you are using.